# Minimal solution for some generalized Pell equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, pell-type-equations

Consider a Pell equation in the form
$$X^2-D Y^2=1$$
such that $(a,b)$ is the minimal solution. Now consider the generalized Pell equation 
$$X^2-DY^2=N^2$$
for some integer $N$: obviously it admits a solution, for example $(Na,Nb)$. My question is: can we say that $(Na,Nb)$ is the minimal solution?

A priori I would answer in a negative way, but can one find at least some conditions on $a,b,D,N$ such that $(Na,Nb)$ is the minimal solution?

Comment: A counterexample is $\ N=7\ $ , $\ D=2\ $ , for which $\ X=9,Y=4\ $ is the minimal solution not being of the desired form.

Comment: I see, thank you! Can we say something more, for example by taking $N$ such that $N^4<D$? It is just because this is the situation where one can use continued fractions (generalized Pell equation $P_D(n)$ with $n^2<D$), maybe this can help... and this rule out your counterexample. Of course, I'm proceeding by trial and error